# How to count the numbers of digit from a file?

Tags: c, io

It's error. What's wrong of my codes?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "ctype.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

FILE* input;
int num;
int numCount = 0;

    input = fopen("123.txt", "r");

    if (!input)
    {
      printf("No file \a\n");
      exit (101);
    }


    while ((fscanf(input, "%d", &num)) == 1)
        printf("%d", num);

    if (isdigit(input))
        numCount++;


    printf("number count: %d", numCount); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what kind of an error are you encountering with, compiler error or runtime error, or maybe it's not working the way you wanted it to? These might help you get some answers

Comment: errorC2664'isdigit'
cannot change from "FILE*" to "int"

Comment: You need to think what "isdigit" does.  Don't let the parameter type (int) confuse you.  It checks a *character* and returns non-zero if the argument passed is a digit.  You definitely don't want the fscanf call in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is completely wrong. You should read individual characters using fgetc() and then test them with isdigit(). The loop should terminate when fgetc() returns EOF.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((fscanf(input, "%d", &num)) == 1)
    printf("%d", num);

if (isdigit(input))
    numCount++;
```

You are only checking `input` once. And you shoul be checking `num` instead, `input` is a `FILE`.

```
while ((fscanf(input, "%d", &num)) == 1){
    printf("%d", num);
    if (isdigit(num))
        numCount++;
}
```

Comment: num is being set by "%d" in the fscanf and isdigit is looking for ASCII values of the 0-9 characters. The "%d" should be changed to "%c" as well, or better yet fgetc

Answer (score 1):

isdigit() tests a character, not a FILE*.

And if you are going to count something, numCount++ should be inside a loop, and not **once in the whole program**