# I am writing a function to do "while" , but why error?

Tags: c, function, while-loop

I am writing a function to do "while" to count the numbers of alphabetic and digits in a text file. I would like to seperate it to 2 functions of 2 "while".
But it error after I create the first function. What's wrong of it?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "ctype.h"

    void countDig (FILE* input, char num, int numCount);

    int _tmain(void)

    {



     FILE* input; 
       char num; 
       char ch;
       int numCount = 0; 
       int chCount = 0;


   input = fopen("123.txt", "r"); 

   if (!input) 
  { 
    printf("No file \a\n"); 
    exit (101); 
  } 



     while ((fscanf(input, " %c", &ch)) == 1)
    { 
      printf(" %c\n", ch); 
      if (isalpha(ch)) 
       chCount++; 

    } 

     countDig (input, num, numCount);







  printf("ch count: %d", chCount); 




    return 0;
}


void countDig (FILE* input, char num, int numCount)
{
    FILE* f;
    char n;
    int nc;


   while ((fscanf(f, " %c", &n)) == 1)
    { 
      printf(" %c\n", n); 
      if (isdigit(n)) 
       nc++; 
    } 
     printf("number count: %d", nc); 

   return;

}
```

---

after correction:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "ctype.h"

void countDig (FILE* input, char num, int numCount);

int _tmain(void)
{
  FILE* input; 
   char num; 
   char ch;
   int numCount = 0; 
   int chCount = 0;

   input = fopen("123.txt", "r"); 

   if (!input) 
  { 
    printf("No file \a\n"); 
    exit (101); 
  } 


     while ((fscanf(input, " %c", &ch)) == 1)
    { 
      printf(" %c\n", ch); 
      if (isalpha(ch)) 
       chCount++; 

    } 

     countDig (input, num, numCount);



  printf("ch count: %d", chCount); 

    return 0;
}


void countDig (FILE* input, char num, int numCount)
{
    char n;
    int nc = 0;


   while ((fscanf(input, " %c", &n)) == 1)
    { 
      printf(" %c\n", n); 
      if (isdigit(n)) 
       nc++; 
    } 
     printf("number count: %d", nc); 

   return;

}
```

Comment: You asked this question yesterday too, didn't you?

Comment: To Prasson: Yes, but the question doesn't only request to count digits. I have tried to finish the question by myself, but I am stupid.

Comment: What warnings does the compiler emit? Any uninitialized local variables?

Comment: "Run-Time Check Failure#3 - The variable 'num' is used without being intialized."

Comment: It's poor form to ask same question so many times in different disguises.  I am confused as to where to reply to your questions, and whether you have solved a particular problem or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896837/c-program-probems-about-isspace is similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892790/c-program-how-to-count-the-numbers-of-digit-from-a-file is same.  In addition, if you had asked the two questions here, we would have been able to tell you an optimal solution to do *both* in one pass over the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `countDig` function takes a `FILE*` but doesn't use it.  Instead it uses an unintialised local `FILE*`:

```
void countDig (FILE* input, char num, int numCount)
{
    FILE* f;
    char n;
    int nc;
    while ((fscanf(f, " %c", &n)) == 1)   // f is uninitialised here
```

You probably meant something like this:

```
void countDig (FILE* input, char num, int numCount)
{
    char n;
    int nc;
    while ((fscanf(input, " %c", &n)) == 1)
```

You're also using `nc` without initialising it - C doesn't automatically set variables to zero; you have to do that yourself:

```
int nc = 0;
```

**Edit** after followup code: As far as I can see you have a couple of other uninitialised variables, but apart from that the code should work.  The only other issue is that `countDig()` may not find anything because the initial loop in `_tmain()` has read all the way to the end of the file.  `countDig()` will continue to read where the main loop finished, which could be the end of the file.

Comment: I have tried, but error again, Ihave posted those codes after correction above.

Comment: To RichieHindle: New codes posted above. But the "Debug Error!" alert is shown when I run it.

Comment: @Programme Newbie: I've edited my answer, but *please post the actual error!* I'm sure the error you're getting says more than just "Debug Error!"

Comment: Yes, "Run-Time Check Failure#3 - The variable 'num' is used without being intialized." also said by the alert.

Comment: @Programme Newbie: Ah, well there you go.  Replace `char num;` with `char num = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

In your `countDig` function, your `File* f;` variable is not initialized, neither is `nc`  that you're incrementing.

Finally in this funciton, what was the intent of the `numCount` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Counting letters you get to the end of the file and then trying to read some more from an uninitialised file handle...

Answer (score 0):

You need to close and re-open the `FILE*`. After the first while loop the `FILE*` is at the end of the file, so when you try to loop through it again in the function it wont work.

Comment: It is pretty normal to close and re-open a file whenever you want to go back to the start. The alternative is to use `fseek( fp, 0, 0 )` which sets the file pointer back to the beginning.