# Problems about "isspace"

Tags: c

I am writing a program to count the number of whitespace characters in a text file.
I use "isspace" to count it. The content in the text file is "1 1 1", but the counter still 0, what's wrong of the codes?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ctype.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

FILE* input; 
char x;
int space = 0;

input = fopen("123.txt", "r");

while ((fscanf(input, " %c", &x)) == 1)
{
   if (isspace(x)) 
   space++; 
}

printf("space : %d\n", space);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've pointed out before, you need to use fgetc(), not fscanf(). fscanf() doesn't read whitepace.

Comment: The format string is wrong.  Instead of " %c", if it were "%c", fscanf will work.  "%c" in *scanf doesn't skip whitespace.  I agree with your conclusion though: much easier to use fgetc/getc rather than fscanf, but using fscanf isn't wrong if one fixes the format string!

Comment: More accurately, the 'scanf' family of functions skip white space at the start of fields other than '%c'.

Answer (score 4):

scanf-family functions will automatically skip whitespace when it's present in the format string. Consider using `fgetc` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I think using `fgetc` (or `getc`) is a better solution in this case, but the other answers are wrong about `fscanf` in this case.  The `scanf` family of functions will not skip whitespace if you use `"%c"` as the format.  The reason your call doesn't work is because you have a whitespace in your format!  So, instead of `" %c"` as the format, you need to use `"%c"` without the leading space.  The leading space is telling `fscanf`: skip all whitespace and then give me the next non-whitespace character.  `fscanf` does this, making sure that any value you get in `x` is *not* a whitespace.  Thus, your `isspace` test is testing a condition that is already known to be false!

You can easily fix it by changing your format specification to `"%c"`.

Having said that, I think it's much better to use `fgetc`/`getc` anyway because, as you have found out, `scanf` family of functions are hard to get right.